# Remove all non integer row from a csv file with sed/grep

Tags: bash, file, shell, csv, special-characters

I have tried using `cat /home/kgh/abc.CSV | awk -F, '$2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/'` . It is checking condition at column level.

```
cat /home/kgh/abc.CSV
1,010116085134,125,125,124,123, 000,00,232,28,294522,077,041755,0074,0013
1,010116085139,125,125,124,123,-012,00,232,28,294522,077,041755,0074,0013
1,010116085144,125,125,124,123, 000,00,232,28,294522,077\82,041755,0074,0013
1,010116085149,125,125,124,123,^@000,00,232,28,294522,088,041755,0074,0013
2,010116084424,15954,15593,14034
2,010116084616,15651,15366,12804
```

expected o/p

```
1,010116085134,125,125,124,123, 000,00,232,28,294522,077,041755,0074,0013
1,010116085139,125,125,124,123,-012,00,232,28,294522,077,041755,0074,0013   
2,010116084424,15954,15593,14034
2,010116084616,15651,15366,12804
```

I am not able to check at row level as `cat /home/kgh/abc.CSV | awk -F, '$0 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/'` . I cannot put this condition for other columns because it contains different number of columns in each row.I want to check only numeric data in my csv file otherwise I want to delete that row from my csv file.Is there any efficient way to do this ? Thanks.

**Edit**

I am worry why the below mentioned solution is not working with `sed` and `grep` 
too

```
root@aa:/home/kgh/# cat abc.CSV
1,010116084135,118,115,113,115,-368,09,225,28,294579,077,044677,0074,0013
1,010116084146,000,000,000,000,000,09,227,28,294536,077,044271,0074,0013
1,010116084151,122,121,118,119,-099,05,228,28,294547,077,044150,0074,0013
1,010116084156,121,117,117,116,-244,^@06,228,28,294557,077,044047,0074,0013
root@aa:/home/kgh# sed -n '/^[0-9, -]*$/p' abc.CSV
root@aa:/home/kgh# sed -rn '/^-?[0-9]+(, ?-?[0-9]+)*$/p' abc.CSV  
root@aa:/home/kgh# grep -v '[^0-9, -]' abc.CSV
```

What am I missing ?

**Edited**

```
file abc.CSV
abc.CSV: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

I opened a file to see CRLF line terminators in vi using `:set list`

```
1,010116084135,118,115,113,115,-368,09,225,28,294579,077,044677,0074,0013$
1,010116084146,000,000,000,000,000,09,227,28,294536,077,044271,0074,0013$
1,010116084151,122,121,118,119,-099,05,228,28,294547,077,044150,0074,0013$
1,010116084156,121,117,117,116,-244,^@06,228,28,294557,077,044047,0074,0013$
```

Hence no result with sed or grep.

I have removed  CRLF line terminators now its working with grep and sed.

```
sed 's/'"$(printf '\015')"'//g' abc.CSV | sed '/[^0-9, -]/d'
1,010116084135,118,115,113,115,-368,09,225,28,294579,077,044677,0074,0013
1,010116084146,000,000,000,000,000,09,227,28,294536,077,044271,0074,0013
1,010116084151,122,121,118,119,-099,05,228,28,294547,077,044150,0074,0013
```

Comment: I'm guessing your CSV file has DOS line terminators. Use `dos2unix` (or one of the many, many alternatives; google around) and try again, or update your regex to allow for this alien character. Plain old `grep` should be all you need, unless you are seeking to also validate e.g. the number of columns, or weed out invalid numbers like 1.2.3 or 0--0.

Comment: Thank you so much for highlighting this :)

Comment: Do you still have issues, or could you accept one of the proposed solutions, so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9, -]*$/p' abc.csv
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" add sed's option `-i`.

Output:

```
1,010116085134,125,125,124,123, 000,00,232,28,294522,077,041755,0074,0013
1,010116085139,125,125,124,123,-012,00,232,28,294522,077,041755,0074,0013
2,010116084424,15954,15593,14034
2,010116084616,15651,15366,12804
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Why am I not able to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

With grep:

```
grep -v '[^0-9, -]' abc.CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

This prints all lines that consist of numbers, separated by commas and an optional space; the numbers are prepended by an optional unary minus.

```
$ sed -rn '/^-?[0-9]+(, ?-?[0-9]+)*$/p' infile
1,010116085134,125,125,124,123, 000,00,232,28,294522,077,041755,0074,0013
1,010116085139,125,125,124,123,-012,00,232,28,294522,077,041755,0074,0013
2,010116084424,15954,15593,14034
2,010116084616,15651,15366,12804
```

Without extended regex (`-r`), the parentheses would have to be escaped, `?` becomes `\{0,1\}` and `+` becomes `\{1,\}`.

Answer (score 0):

Another method using grep:
**grep '^[0-9, -]*$' abc.csv**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `sed` *print* command, you can alternatively use the `sed` *delete* command to delete any lines that contain characters other than `'0-9, -'`. For example:

```
$sed '/[^0-9, -]/d' abc.csv
1,010116085134,125,125,124,123, 000,00,232,28,294522,077,041755,0074,0013
1,010116085139,125,125,124,123,-012,00,232,28,294522,077,041755,0074,0013
2,010116084424,15954,15593,14034
2,010116084616,15651,15366,12804
```

**note:** to 'edit-in-place', you can use the `'-i'` option. Additionally, you can use the `'-i.bak'` option to have `sed` create `abc.csv.bak` containing the original file with the modified file in `abc.csv`.

Comment: with -i option, its getting ovewrite as Empty file,because I am not getting any o/p after sed '/[^0-9, -]/d' abc.csv

Comment: What operating system are you using? I am using the exact same file and expression on Linux and it is working as indicated. Are you on Mac?